# Insider knowledge vs. insider's knowledge vs. inside knowledge

Tags: phrases, differences

What is the difference between these three phrases:

1. To have **insider's knowledge** about something.
2. To have **inside knowledge** about something.
3. To have **insider knowledge** about something.

Comment: They are all valid ways of saying much the same thing. In the case of number 3, I would hyphenate "insider-knowledge".

Comment: I do have insider knowledge that they are different.

Comment: By all means enlighten us. But, if you know the answer, I am puzzled as to why you asked the question. Or, at least, why did you not include all your relevant information?

Answer (score 0):

In this context:
insider's - infers a group who posseses the knowledge.
inside - infers the ownership or possession of the knowledge.
insider - an individual within a group having the knowledge.